# Can This Be Made Tail Recursive?

Tags: scala, future, spray, tail-recursion

I'm hitting an HTTP endpoint that returns a paginated JSON response. The value of 'meta.next'
 in my response type points to the next page of the response. When this value is null, there are no more pages
 to retrieve.
 I'm using Spray IO to make the HTTP requests.  I collect the entries of interest in each
 page response and concatenate that with what has been collected so far. When next becomes
 null, I return all collected entries.
 My question: Is there a way to make the 'getJson(...)' function below tail recursive?

```
 case class JsonResponse(meta: Meta, items: List[Item])

 val pipeline: Future[HttpRequest => Future[JsonResponse]] = for (
    Http.HostConnectorInfo(connector, _) <-
    IO(Http) ? Http.HostConnectorSetup("somehost.com", port = 80)
  ) yield sendReceive(connector) ~> unmarshal[JsonResponse]


  // .....

  def getJson(relativeUrl: String)(implicit m: Monoid[Future[List[JsObject]]]) : Future[List[JsObject]] = {

    val jsr = pipeline.flatMap(_(Get(relativeUrl)))

    // Grab only those entries that we are interested in
    val objList = jsr.map(js => js.items.collect{ case o if(o.whatever.isDefined) => o.toJson.asJsObject })

    jsr.flatMap(js => js.meta.next.map(next => m.append(getJson(next), objList)).getOrElse(objList))
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tail recursion doesn't really apply here. When you use future combinators you are not operating on a single stack.

Concretely, `getJson` immediately returns in every case. By using `jsr.flatMap` you are registering a callback which will be called only when the response for the HTTP request has been received. The next invocation of `getJson` will therefore also happen in this context, i.e. on the callback stack provided by the implicit execution context.

So, while recursion is still happening on an algorithmic level it doesn't lead to adding up stack frames on the stack of one (or any) thread.

With regard to blowing the stack your code is fine. Is there another reason you want to use tail recursion?

Comment: Ah. Thank you! Yes, the only reason I wanted to use tail recursion was fear of blowing my stack. This could potentially end up handling many pages before returning. Thanks so much for your clear explanation. I feel kinda stoopid now for not realizing this, but also very relieved.

Comment: No, worries. As powerful as `Future`s are as a new general asynchronous execution primitive, so hard is it at the beginning to get a grasp of how the execution flows in all the different possible scenarios.